# Kubernetes Operator Vs Helm for Pub-Sub Model application

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, publish-subscribe, k3s, kubernetes-operator

I have a Publisher Subscriber (Pub-Sub model) application in C# and I want to host it on Kubernetes for high availability. Is it good to go with helm or shall I use operators in my application.
What is best suited for Pub-Sub model applications ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a (dockerized) application and you want to run it in Kubernetes, then it's enough if you [create Kubernetes Deployment configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment).

So the simplest thing you can do is to create a file `deployment.yaml` with the following content.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: <your-docker-image>
```

And then deploy it in Kubernetes with the following command.

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
```

About **Helm** and **Operators**, you generally use them for some more complex deployments, to organize and template multiple Kubernetes configurations, to interact with your application, to perform backups, and more operational tasks.

Comment: (Even for this absolute minimum Deployment, I'd consider using Helm to supply the image's tag and to be able to support multiple concurrent installations.)

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned on the previous answer simple deployment would be enough for you to launch an application in Kubernetes.

Idea of helm is to have reusable yaml artifacts thru templates. So it allows you to define Kubernetes yamls files with some properties. Values for those properties are stored in separate file. Most use case for helm is to create custom yamls for the same application workload with different configuration or scheduling those deployment in different environments.

Kubernetes Operator on the other hand is an application-specific controller that extends the functionality of the Kubernetes API to create, configure, and manage instances of complex applications on behalf of a Kubernetes user. It builds upon the basic Kubernetes resource and controller concepts, but includes domain or application-specific knowledge to automate the entire life cycle of the software it manages.

So if you some special requirements that your application needs you may want to be more interested in creating custom operator.

To sum up one could say that helm is sort of package manager for Kubernetes where Kubernetes operator is a controller which manages the life cycle of particular kubernetes resource/application/software/

Here's a good [article](https://cloudark.medium.com/kubernetes-operators-and-helm-it-takes-two-to-tango-3ff6dcf65619) how does two differs and what they have in common.